# How do I save several running ping thread feedback/results to each related file output?

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, logging, ping

I have written below script in linux shell script, for pinging several routers in parallel  and save output to files and other script analysis for packet lost on links. as you can see all pings run in background and simulate parralelism or multithreading.

```
for  ips  in  100.28.139.5  100.20.12.90  100.23.13.74  100.25.131.10
do 
ping $ips -s 500  -c 500 &> ${ips}.500.text & 
ping $ips -s 1500 -c 500 &> ${ips}.1500.text & 
ping $ips -s 4500 -c 500 &> ${ips}.4500.text & 
done
```

I have tried rewrite it by java but I find it so big(>100 lines) and I didn't able to save the thread results to related ping file output.
I need dedicate logger for each thread, to save outputs.

**How do I save several running ping thread feedback/results to each related file output?**

Answer (score 1):

When you create your thread, using the costructor you will pass him certain data: suppose the url to be pinged. Using such a information you create your own file on disk where to output data coming from ping feedback.